# How to disable the 'Searching for GPS' notification on Android

Tags: android, notifications, gps

i am getting this notification "searching for gps" every time even after logout the app, How to disable this notification?

Comment: share your code

Comment: `disable this notification` you can't as you didn't show it. What you can do is remove reason of this notification was shown. You requested the location in your app, but didn't remove your request when your app finishes.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
locationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(GPSLocationListener.this);
```

or:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);
```